# How to communicate with (or about) one senior staff member who is bringing everyone down?

Tags: manager

So there are about 20-25 of us in my workplace, including the owner who is also the boss. He has 3 or 4 employees who are just below his level and then the rest of us. One of those 3 or 4 employees is making life miserable for everyone. She moans constantly. She is always complaining about being overworked (but we’re all overworked) and trying to push tasks onto other people.

For example, she had 6 specific phone calls that she was responsible for today. She got me to do 3 of them (she has the right to give me instructions, but technically it wasn’t my job role) and then complained to the owner/boss about having too many phone calls to do.
She also came up to me at 2pm and ranted that she hadn’t had any lunch yet because she’s so overworked. Well neither had I, but the last thing I would do is complain about it to someone who wasn’t responsible for the scheduling.

She also made a decision in the staff meeting while the boss was not present that massively reduced her workload but increased it for about 5 other people. When the boss found out later he told us to leave things as they originally were for now.

She has threatened to quit multiple times due to the stress of our workplace but hasn’t actually done it. It’s led to mass accommodation to get her to stay as many of the clients like her and she’s great with them.

Essentially, she will moan at another member of staff and then they will moan at someone else or create a storm about her complaint to try to fix it for her... it’s making everyone else even more stressed.

Is there anything I can do either to respond to her, or to respond to the domino effect of extra work and complaining managers and boss she causes?

Comment: Why the close vote as off-topic? This seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Answer (score 7):

"Never murder someone who is committing suicide", as the saying goes.

This person is destroying themselves, and the boss knows it.  Do not provide a distraction by interfering

Comment: **Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.** - Napoleon Bonaparte

Comment: @IconDaemon Napolean actually said “Then, gentlemen, let us wait a little; when your enemy is executing a false movement, never interrupt him.”

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. Ignore her moaning. She's just digging herself deeper at this point.

Just focus on your work and let her carry on as she is. By the looks of it, this isn't a new occurrence so you and everyone else should have some degree of familiarity with it, however annoying or stressful it may be.

She's moaned to the boss, so they're already aware of it. If they're competent enough, they'd be working on either finding a replacement or getting someone to share her workload to at least alleviate the moaning so she still can stay for the sake of the clients who like her.